# React componentDidMount is not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have following route in React:

```
<Route
    path={`${this.props.match.path}horoskop`}
    render={() => <HoroscopeController
        horoscopeService={this.horoscopeService}
        fortuneTellerService={this.fortuneTellerService}/>}/>
```

and the following Controller:

```
class HoroscopeController extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log("hejhej");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("testing);
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I always see "hejhej" in the console (from the constructor) and when I go to `http://localhost:3000/horoskop` I see "testing" in the console, but not when I go to for example `http://localhost:3000/horoskop/vattumannen`. I have tried going directly to the subpath in an incognito browser but it does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add an asterisk at the end of the path in your route definition, like this:

```
path={`${this.props.match.path}horoskop*`}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work for me. I have the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Sorry, the code contains a lot of company secrets, and I cannot show it. Thanks for trying to help.